# htaccess redirection rules with conditions

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I used the following code in my htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . index.php
 </IfModule>
```

It redirects as if the url is test.com/test --> it redirects to test folder (Here the folder is available in the name of 'test')
If the url is  test.com/testpage --> it redircts to index.php (i.e no one folder is in the name of testpage)

But i want to redirect this as

if the url is test.com --> it will redircts to index.php

if the url is test.com/test --> It will redirects to corresponding folder (if the folder name exists)

if the url is test.com/testpage then it redirects to page.php

Also i want to redirect some particular name to test.php (test.com/test2 or test.com/test3)

Please help this

Answer (score 0):

This is done by creating a router class.

The code you have there redirects all urls to index.php making index be able to read the url and base it's contect on that.

see http://www.phpaddiction.com/tags/axial/url-routing-with-php-part-one/

for router tutorial

Answer (score 0):

you can individually write their rewrite conditions for specific pages/urls or just add some sort of suffix like along with page pass "[category]/testpage" or any thing and describe the rewrite condition so that it can be redirected.

RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ page.php [R=301]